# Angularjs in IE dropdowns in ng-repeat do not render correctly

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of components, each of these components has a dropdown (or `select`) control. I render these components using `ng-repeat`. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't in IE10.
In IE10 if I have the following:

```
<select ng-model="selection.selected_id">
  <option value="" ng-selected="!selection.selected_id" ng-hide="selection.selected_id">
    Select one
  </option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" 
              ng-selected="option.id === selection.selected_id"
              value="{{option.id}}">
    {{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Initially I can see `{{option.name}}` in a dropdown. Only when I actually click on the dropdown the correct value renders. Investigating the DOM, I can see correct values in HTML, it seems like the IE itself doesn't render them correctly.
It is fine if the select is not within ng-repeat itself!
Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsqvstmp/7/), run it in Chrome (works fine) and then in IE10 (doesn't work). I am using latest angular (1.5.1).
Is there a fix for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works fine in **IE 11**

not very sure about the problem but yes data-ng-bind is always better option than using {{}}

and

try with **ng-options** in select tag. it should work as already tested on IE10
please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I initially started with ng-options. But for the limitations it introduces (mainly I can't disable option selected in one dropdown to make it unselectable in another) I can't use it.

Comment: I used ng-options in the end, with some fancy magic to disable entries in respective dropdown boxes. It fixed the problem. I still consider the issue I encountered a bug, just not sure it it is IE or Angular....

Comment: So basically there is no "simple "solution if it's mandatory to support IE9?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this directive. I use this to fix ng-options issue on IE9-IE10

```
.directive('fixCrappyIeSelect', function () {
       return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                options: '=fixCrappyIeSelect'
            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function ($scope, $element) {
                $scope.$watch('options', function () {
                    $element.hide();
                    $element.show();
                });
            }]
        };
    });
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: `.hide()` and `.show()` have been dropped from Angular at some point, and they are not available in 1.5.1